# CheckBox Data to ListBox (VBNet)

Tags: vb.net, checkbox, listbox

the problem with my code is that when i initially select a particular checkbox it works well and displays selected item in listbox, but when selected again it creates another entry within the listbox and when i remove it i have to uncheck the same checkbox the times it has been displayed in the listbox when i click the btnSubmit.

Can someone tell me what's wrong with the code, thank you so much

```
Private Sub btnSubmit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSubmit.Click
    If CheckBox1.Checked Then
        ListBox1.Items.Add(CheckBox1.Text)
    Else
        ListBox1.Items.Remove(CheckBox1.Text)
    End If
    If CheckBox2.Checked Then
        ListBox1.Items.Add(CheckBox2.Text)
    Else
        ListBox1.Items.Remove(CheckBox2.Text)
    End If
    If CheckBox3.Checked Then
        ListBox1.Items.Add(CheckBox3.Text)
    Else
        ListBox1.Items.Remove(CheckBox3.Text)
    End If
    If CheckBox4.Checked Then
        ListBox1.Items.Add(CheckBox4.Text)
    Else
        ListBox1.Items.Remove(CheckBox4.Text)
    End If
    If CheckBox5.Checked Then
        ListBox1.Items.Add(CheckBox5.Text)
    Else
        ListBox1.Items.Remove(CheckBox5.Text)
    End If
    If CheckBox6.Checked Then
        ListBox1.Items.Add(CheckBox6.Text)
    Else
        ListBox1.Items.Remove(CheckBox6.Text)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: If you use `ListBox1.Items.Clear()` as the first line in that method, then you won't need any of the `Else` and `.Remove` lines.

Comment: Sir which line should I add ListBox1.Items.Clear()?

Comment: @JohnnyNitro The very first line.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
Private Sub btnSubmit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSubmit.Click
    ListBox1.Items.Clear
    CheckObj(CheckBox1)
    CheckObj(CheckBox2)
    CheckObj(CheckBox3)
    CheckObj(CheckBox4)
    CheckObj(CheckBox5)
    CheckObj(CheckBox6)
End Sub

Sub CheckObj (obj as Checkbox)
  if obj.checked then ListBox1.Items.Add (obj.text)
End Sub
```